# find substring index in array using Java

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to return the index of a user-input substring from a Character array using Java. The array is initialized, scrambled, then searched. I'm new to this and have tried two different approaches with no success. What am I overlooking? Thanks in advance.

Approach 1:

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;

public class ArrayRandomChar {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create an array of characters:
    Character[] anArray = {'P', 'A', 'P', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'R'};
    for (char ch: anArray)
    System.out.print(ch + " ");
    System.out.println();

    // Create list from array and shuffle
    List<Character> aList = Arrays.asList(anArray);
    Collections.shuffle(aList);
    System.out.print(aList);
    System.out.println();

    // Bring back into array
    Object ob[] = aList.toArray();
    for (Object ch: anArray)
    System.out.print((Character) ch + " ");

    // User input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String letter = input.next();
    System.out.println(letter);

    // Return index of letter, -1 if doesn't contain
    int retval = aList.IndexOf(letter);
    System.out.println(retval);

    }
      }
```

**Issue:** when running document and inputting a letter, **-1** is returned even if the list contains the letter.

Approach 2:

```
public class ArrayRandomChar {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create an array of characters:
    Character[] anArray = {'P', 'A', 'P', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'R'};
    for (char ch: anArray)
        System.out.print(ch + " ");
    System.out.println();

    // Create list from array:
    List<Character> aList = Arrays.asList(anArray);
    Collections.shuffle(aList);
    System.out.print(aList);
    System.out.println();

    //create array from list
    Object ob[] = aList.toArray();
    for (Object ch: anArray)
        System.out.print((Character) ch + " ");

    //user input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String letter = input.next();
    int index = Arrays.binarySearch(anArray, letter);
    System.out.println(~index);
    System.out.println(letter);

    }
      }
```

This throws exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Character
at java.lang.Character.compareTo(Character.java:101)
at java.util.Arrays.binarySearch0(Arrays.java:2001)
at java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(Arrays.java:1943)
at ArrayRandomChar.main(ArrayRandomChar.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message?

Comment: Everything beginning with 'at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)'

I'm wondering if this could be solved with a Character compatible Scanner input.next().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***This will solve the issue..***

**Approach 1:**

```
int retval = aList.indexOf(letter.charAt(0));
```

**Approach 2:**

```
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(anArray, letter.charAt(0));
```

The problem is that you are having a character Array `aList`, and the `letter` is a String and hence it search for a `String` in the Character array. Which can possibly cause `ClassCastException` or String not found.

> **In short :** `Character A` is not same as `String A`

Answer (score 1):

*Approach 1:*

> when running document and inputting a letter, -1 is returned even if
>   the list contains the letter.

ok, this problems @Dileep has already answered,

```
int retval = aList.IndexOf(letter);
```

Mistake is that you have passed a `String` type to `List.indexOf(Object o)` were, `aList`
contains all elements of type `Character`. So `List.indexOf()` will always return -1.

you may change to work:

```
int retval = aList.indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(letter.charAt(0)));
```

<sub>Note: Character.toUpperCase() i have used because you have all elements in upper case.</sub>

---

*Approach 2:*

throws

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Character
```

exception message has already answered, that `String` cannot be a changed/cast to `Character`,

```
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(anArray, letter);
```

Here,

- `anArray` contains elements type of `Character`
- you have passed a `String` to `Arrays.binarySearch()`, instead of a `char` or `Character`, internally when `Arrays#binarySearch()` invokes `Character.compareTo(T o)`
  here, the specified object's type(i.e. `letter#String`) prevents it from being compared to Character object. then the `ClassCastException` is throwed.

Solution:

```
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(anArray, Character.toUpperCase(letter.charAt(0)));
```

Comment: I'm aiming for a randomized scramble of a pre-defined Character array. How would Arrays.sort() affect this?

Comment: @user25976 Sorry, i have not noticed that in your question. if you aiming for a randomized scramble, then no use of `Arrays.sort()` in that case. i will update the answer.