# Comparing items of different types--user input and index return (using Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I've created an array and scrambled it. Now, I'd like to compare a user input to items in array to return all indexes where the input occurs. Through help from this thread, I'm able to return the first index where the input occurs: [find substring index in array using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753794/find-substring-index-in-array-using-java) Now, using a loop, I'd like to find ALL indexes where input occurs (in case there's more than one). However, my output is wacky. I'm very new to this and am not getting anywhere by reading the Java API.

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ArrayRandomChar {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create an array of characters:
  Character[] anArray = {'P', 'A', 'P', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'R'};
  for (char ch: anArray)
    System.out.print(ch + " ");
    System.out.println();

    List<Character> aList = Arrays.asList(anArray);
    Collections.shuffle(aList);
    System.out.print(aList);
    System.out.println();


    Object ob[] = aList.toArray();
    for (Object ch: anArray)
    System.out.print((Character) ch + " ");

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("This program initializes a secret word or phrase to be guessed by you!");
    System.out.println("Enter an uppercase letter to return all indexes where it occurs in scrambled string: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String letter = input.next();

    System.out.println(letter);
    System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(letter.charAt(0)));

    List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int i;
    //Loop to find index of inputted character
    for (i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++){
      Character ch = new Character(anArray[i]);
      if (Character.toUpperCase(letter.charAt(0)) == ch) {
        int index = aList.indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(letter.charAt(0)));
        myList.add(index);
      }
    }
     System.out.println(myList);

    }
      }
```

Actual Output:

> run ArrayRandomChar
>   P A P A B E A R 
>   [E, A, A, R, P, A, B, P]
>   E A A R P A B P 
>   This program initializes a secret word or phrase to be guessed by you!
>   Enter an uppercase letter to return all indexes where it occurs in scrambled string: 
>    [DrJava Input Box]
>   A
>   A
>   [1, 1, 1]

Desired Output:

> run ArrayRandomChar
>   P A P A B E A R 
>   [E, A, A, R, P, A, B, P]
>   E A A R P A B P 
>   This program initializes a secret word or phrase to be guessed by you!
>   Enter an uppercase letter to return all indexes where it occurs in scrambled string: 
>    [DrJava Input Box]
>   A
>   A
>   [1, 2, 5]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Character ch = new Character(anArray[i]);
```

instead of

```
Character[] ch = new Character(anArray[i]);
```

`new Character()` will create Character not `Character[]`

**And**

also change the below line.

```
if (Character.toUpperCase(letter.charAt(0)) == ch) {
```

instead of

```
if (Character.toUpperCase(letter.charAt(0)).equals(ch) == True) {
```

Because the return value of `.toUperCase` should be a primitive char so there is no `.equals` method you can simple check by using `==`

Comment: that does go through the compilation errors, but now my output isn't what I expected. I've updated my question a little.

Comment: change the following code it gives the index of the given character. In your code you are getting again and again same value, beacause the value A will appear in the first index of the array so only it gives the same value. Now try this it will gives the correct value. Replace the below code,    for (i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++)
        {
            Character ch = new Character(anArray[i]);
            if (Character.toUpperCase(letter.charAt(0)) == ch)
            {
                myList.add(i);
            }
        }